# Facebook PHP share from my website

Tags: php, facebook

Dudes
When you share something on Facebook (e.g. from Twitterfeed), it puts the icon and link for Twitterfeed website under the shared thing in this format:

*icon goes here* 2 hours ago via twitterfeed · Comment · Like

How can I make a page in my website send its icon and linked name?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to build your own Facebook app which can publish to Facebook:
http://www.facebook.com/developers/apps.php

In case you're on a wordpress blog you can use the plugin Simple Facebook Connect which makes it all pretty easy:
http://ottopress.com/wordpress-plugins/simple-facebook-connect/

Cheers!